# angular promise - $q when error on one of the call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

I have an array and I do for loop on the array. for eeach item - i do rest call and save it in the array restArr;

```
angular.foreach(myItems , function(item){
    var q = $http.get("someHttpCall").succsee(function(){}).error(function(){});

    restArr.push(q);
}
```

then i use $q

```
$q.all(restArr).then(function(){

    doSomething();

});
```

Firstly, what happend if one of the call returned with error?
And second -  there is a way to start again call that return with error?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If one of the promises within a `$q.all` is rejected, the overall promise is rejected. The rejection value is the same as that from the one rejected promise.

Catch the rejection, then handle your retry logic in the catch handler.

```
$q.all(restArr)
  .then(doSomething)
  .catch(handleError);
```